# Python 2.7: Handeling Unicode Objects

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

I have an application that needs to be able to handle non-ASCII characters of unknown encoding. The program may delete or replace these characters (if they are discovered in a user dictionary file), otherwise they need to pass cleanly through unaltered. What's mind-boggling is, it works one minute, then I make some seemingly trivial change, and now it fails with UnicodeDecode, UnicodeEncode, or kindred errors. Addressing this has led me down the road of cargo cult programing--making random tweaks that get it working again, but I have no idea why. Is there a general-purpose solution for dealing this, perhaps even the creation of class that modifies the normal way Python deals with strings?

I'm not sure what code to include as about five separate modules are involved. Here is what I am doing in abstract terms:

Taking a text from one of two sources: text that the user has pasted directly into a Tkinter toplevel window; text captured from the Win32 clipboard via a hotkey command.

The text is processed, including the removal of whitespace charters, then certain characters/words are replaced or simply deleted based on a customizable user dictionary.

The result is then returned to the Tkinter GUI or the Win32 clipboard, depending on whether or not the keyboard shortcut was used.

Some details that may be relevant:

All modules use

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

The user dictionary is saved in UTF-16 LE with BOM (a function removes BOM characters when parsing the file). The file object is instantiated with

```
self.pf = codecs.open(self.pattern_fn, 'r', 'utf-16')
```

The text entry points for text are via a Tkinter GUI Text widget:

```
text = self.paste_to_field.get(1.0, Tkinter.END)
```

Or from the clipboard:

```
text = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT)
```

And example error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u201d' in position
 2: character maps to <undefined>
```

Furthermore, the same text might work when tested on OS X (where I do development work) but cause an error on Windows.

Regular expressions are used, however in this case no non-ASCIIs are included in the pattern. For non-ASCIIs I simply

```
text = text.replace(old, new)
```

Another thing to consider: for c in text type iterations are no good because a non-ASCII may look like several characters to Python. The normal word/character distinction no longer holds. Also, using bad_letter = repr(non_ASCII) doesn't help since str(bad_letter) merely returns a string of the escape sequence--it can't restore the original character.

Sorry if this is extremely vague. Please let me know what info I can provide to help clarify. Thanks in advance for reading this.

Comment: Use the strategy that Python 3 uses - every input gets converted immediately to Unicode (with `decode`), and every output gets converted back to bytes as you write it (with `encode`). That will make it much more obvious where your assumptions are wrong or when you have bad data.

Comment: If I call `text = self.paste_to_field.get(1.0, Tkinter.END).decode('utf-8')` I get an immediate error upon hitting a `> 128`. Unless you're saying I need a `decode()` somewhere within Tkinter? Incidentally, applying `text + u''` immediately after the `get()` method call seems to have "fixed" the problem.

Comment: The Windows clipboard will have two modes of access, one being `utf-16le` and the other being whichever code page your version of Windows is configured for. `utf-8` would only be a possibility if Tkinter was automatically decoding and reencoding the text for you.

Comment: I've made an edit to hopefully clarify. The text can enter one of two ways: a Text widget in the GUI or it gets pulled from the clipboard via a separate module/thread that involves hotkey registration. Both are problematic--the latter thread is kept alive with exception handlers and somehow works in spite of errors. The former now works with unicode quotes `u''` applied but, no argument that I can call decode with works consistently.